# Difference between linux network connection errors

Tags: linux, networking, rust

I've been coding a port scanner in Rust, and for detecting open ports what I do is create a `TcpStream` and try to connect to different ports on a given host to see if it allows the connection.

The problem I'm having is that when the connection fails, the OS (Linux) returns one of three codes:

```
101 - It is displayed if network is unreachable.
111 - It is displayed if connection is refused.
113 - It is displayed if there is no route to host.
```

And I've been looking for in-depth explanations of each error and what causes them, but I just find the same text over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

- *Network unreachable* → most likely explanation is that your computer is not connected to any network (Wi-Fi down, ethernet unplugged, …)
- *Connection refused* means that you were able to reach the target computer, but that it refused the connection → no application is listening on the requested port on the other computer, or the firewall blocked the connection.
- *No route to host* means that you were unable to reach the target computer. Either it is off, or there is a problem somewhere in the network between your computer and the target.

Comment: Network unreachable -> you do not have a route to the host. For example you do not have a default gateway set and you want to reach 8.8.8.8, you most probably will get a Network unreachable:

`[student@rhel8 ~]$ sudo ip ro add default via 10.0.1.1`. 
`[student@rhel8 ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1`
`PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=1.18 ms`
`[student@rhel8 ~]$ sudo ip ro del default`
`[student@rhel8 ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1`
`connect: Network is unreachable`
`[student@rhel8 ~]$`